# Is it possible to change icon's position on FAB?

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to move the arrow a little to the right.

[image: FAB]

Comment: Can you edit the icon's file and change it there?

Comment: if u change floating button then possible

Comment: it is a vector. I don't really know how to edit it.

Comment: this is play button vector?

Comment: no, black round is fab, arrow is vector

Comment: this single problem is easy to deal with, what I want is solution for this kind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can edit your icon to move it a little to the right.

- If you use **Raster** image, just use image editor, which you like and move it.
- If you use **Vector** image, you can wrap your `path` data with `group` and add `scale` and `pivot` to the image:

Initial vector file:

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="24dp"
    android:height="24dp"
    android:viewportHeight="24.0"
    android:viewportWidth="24.0">
    <path
        android:fillColor="#FF000000"
        android:pathData="M8,5v14l11,-7z" />
</vector>
```

Image moved to the right:

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="24dp"
    android:height="24dp"
    android:viewportHeight="24.0"
    android:viewportWidth="24.0">
    <group
        android:pivotX="-30"
        android:scaleX="0.95"
        android:scaleY="0.95">
        <path
            android:fillColor="#FF000000"
            android:pathData="M8,5v14l11,-7z" />
    </group>
</vector>
```

FAB now looks in a next way:

[image]

You can move your image to any side using `pivotX` and `pivotY`.

Answer (score 0):

No corresponding attribute.

Only possible via editing drawables.

Way to alter vectors on [Android ref](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/VectorDrawable.html).